# How to use element ui for pagination in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

How to make this layout="prev, pager, next" working (back end). I need to put value in `next_page` and `prev_page`. I have looked up in documentation but i got nothing.

```
<el-pagination
@current-change="handleCurrentChange"
:current-page="current_page"
:page-size="per_page"
layout="prev, pager, next"
:total="total">
</el-pagination>

 <script>
data() {
return {
        per_page: null,
        current_page: null,
        total: null,
        next_page_url: null,

    }
  },
created(){
  this.fetchPost();
},
methods: {
    fetchPost() {
    axios.get('/' + this.$route.params.trans + '/adminGetPosts')
    .then(({data}) => {
        this.posts = data.data
        this.current_page= data.current_page
        this.per_page = data.per_page
        this.total = data.total
        this.next_page_url = data.next_page_url
    })
    },
 </script>
```

Comment: You forgot to implement handleCurrentChange handler in your methods section

Answer (score -5):

Written on the document is very clear.
layout="prev, pager, next"  is Page layout.
Example:

```js
new Vue().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="block">
  <span class="demonstration">页数较少时的效果</span>
  <el-pagination layout="prev, pager, next" :total="50">
  </el-pagination>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span class="demonstration">大于 7 页时的效果</span>
  <el-pagination layout="prev, pager, next, jumper, ->, total" :total="1000">
  </el-pagination>
</div>
</div>
```

API: http://element.eleme.io/#/zh-CN/component/pagination

Comment: But If I click next, it's not changing the data (page 2). current_page and total already working very well. But prev and next not working for back end.